# how to retrieve checked value from database in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i need to show checked values in checkbox from a db column (named "course")

my controller

```
public function CheckBoxUpdate($id=0)
{
    $data['course_taken']=$this->StudentModel->getInvoice($id);
    $this->load->view('site' ,$data);
}
```

My model

```
public function getInvoice($id=0)
{
    return $this->db->select('*')
            ->from('checkbox')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->get()->row_array();
}
```

My view

```
<?php 

  $course=explode(",",$course_taken['course']);

  print_r ($course);

?>

<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" name="course[]" value="<?php echo $course_taken['course'];?>"   >
<label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1"><?php echo $course_taken['course'];?></label>
```

My database

```
id       course
===     ========
1       option1,option2
```

How can i display these to selected item in checkbox as checked in codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a set of the whole checkboxes named `$checkboxes` like this :

```
<?php
$checkboxes = array(
    '0' => 'option0', 
    '1' => 'option1', 
    '2' => 'option2', 
    '3' => 'option3', 
    '4' => 'option4', 
    '5' => 'option5', 
);
?>
```

Looking at your controller, I assume you have all the checked item as `$course_taken`.
You could display both the checked and unchecked item like this :

```
<?php
$course = explode(",",$course_taken['course']);
foreach ($checkboxes as $key => $value) {
?>
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox<?php echo $key ?>" name="course[]" value="<?php echo $value ?>" <?php echo in_array($value, $course)?'checked="checked"':'' ?> >
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $value ?></label>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's i can do for you.. try it.

```
$courses=array('option1','option2'); //type manually all your course option
$purposesFromDB= $pr['purpose'];
$coursesFromDBArray=explode(',',$coursesFromDB); //explode data from database 
   foreach($purposesFull as $opt){
   $checked = in_array($opt,$purposesFromDBArray) ? 'checked' : ''; //check if it's in the array
   echo '<input type="checkbox" name="options[]"'.$checked.'>'.$opt;
```

Comment: i need to call options dynamically, bcoz these options are coming from another db table

Comment: call the options from another table. make sure the data is in array form then store that to variable $courses.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
$course=explode(",",$course_taken['course']);

<?php if(count($course) > 0): 
      foreach($course as $row):?>

    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" name="course[]" value="<?= $row ?>"  <?php if($row == 'course-name'){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?> >
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1"><?= $row ?></label>

<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```